# Crosstalk print selected item in R

Tags: r

I couldn't print item that I selected.

For example:

```
shared_quakes <- crosstalk::SharedData$new(quakes[sample(nrow(quakes), 100),])
crosstalk::bscols(
  crosstalk::filter_checkbox("lat", "latitude", shared_quakes, ~lat, inline = TRUE))
```

I want to print longitude of the selected item like print(shared_quakes,~lon).

Thank you.